# Add more conditions to the formula

Tags: google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates, importrange, google-sheets-arrays

[image: On the bottom of the my sheet I added some conditions, if I deleted one of them the whole my query with the information goes wrong, importing a lot of empty cell, how to add in my formula in order to get something like this: if one of B2, C2, D2 is empty then import only the rows, that contains one of these DE,ME,MN]

```
=query({IMPORTRANGE("1c6ihzJjzD_Nhbz5rB1s0485PS98V-Q4bfVAiIon5vSA","MC2!A11:S5000")}, 
"select Col19, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15, Col18 
where Col5 is not null 
and Col8 contains '"&B2&"'
or Col8 contains '"&C2&"'
or Col8 contains '"&D2&"' 
order by Col6 asc",0)
```

Comment: On the bottom of the my sheet I added some conditions, if I deleted one of them the whole my query with the information goes wrong, importing a lot of empty cell, how to add in my formula in order to get something like this: 
**if one of B2, C2, D2 is empty then import only the rows, that contains one of these DE,ME,MN